# Assign stored title attributes from one array to elements stored in another. jquery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I have twelve `<span>`'s with the class "has_title". Each has a unique `title`.

I also have twelve `<div>`'s with the class "bar".

I need to assign the titles from the `<span>`'s in the order that they appear in the html to the `<div>`'s in the order that *they* appear in the html.

My idea was to use `.each` to store the titles in an array and then somehow loop through the array applying the titles to each of the `<div>`'s in turn

So far I have the following code which stores the values of the titles in an array:

```
var myarr = [];
$(".has_title").each(function(){
    myarr.push({ title: this.title});
});
```

And the following that loops through the array:

```
$.each(myarr, function() {
    // What goes here?
});
```

That's where I get stuck though. Am I even going about this in the right way? 
A little help would be great as I am about to throw my laptop through the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var myarr = [];
$(".has_title").each(function(){
    myarr.push({ title: this.title});
});

$(".bar").each( function(index) {
    $(this).attr('title', myarr[index].title);
});
```

Comment: +1 - This solution is just *better* than mine. I can't believe I didnt think of that.

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this:

```
 var titles = [];
 $('.has_title').each(function()
 {
     titles.push(this.title);
 });

 $(titles).each(function(index)
 {
     $('.bar:eq(' + index + ')').title = this;
 });
```

Should do the trick. Basically, use the callback which takes the index of the set, and then use the `:eq()` selector to find the div in the set of that index and assign the title.